# Jasmine to test window.setTimeout

Tags: javascript, web, jasmine

I have the following code which I need to test using jasmine and I seem to be stuck

```
timeoutCallback () {
var self = this;
self.$window.setTimeout(function() {
  self.$window.location.href = 'www.google.com';
}, 400);
}
```

I keep on getting the following error in my existing jasmine test which call the callback

```
'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'self.$window.setTimeout(function () {
    self.$window.location.href = 'www.google.com';
  }, 400)') (line 183)
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that self.$window not have the setTimeout function, why you don't use the default setTimeout function like this?

```
timeoutCallback () {
  var self = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    self.$window.location.href = 'www.google.com';
  }, 400);
}
```

Comment: How about use a default window object reference for relocation as well, so `window.location.href` ...